# Import particular Colums of csv in database in php/sql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a CSV which contains 15 columns.

But I want to import only 2 columns from the CSV in database.

whats should I do?

I tried importing but it's importing all the columns.

```
<?php

//database connection details
$connect = mysql_connect('localhost','root','123456');

if (!$connect) {
 die('Could not connect to MySQL: ' . mysql_error());
}

//your database name
$cid =mysql_select_db('test',$connect);

// path where your CSV file is located
define('CSV_PATH','C:/wamp/www/');

// Name of your CSV file
$csv_file = CSV_PATH . "test.csv"; 


if (($handle = fopen($csv_file, "r")) !== FALSE) {
   fgetcsv($handle);   
   while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
          $col[$c] = $data[$c];
        }

 $col1 = $col[0];
 $col2 = $col[1];
 $col3 = $col[2];

// SQL Query to insert data into DataBase
$query = "INSERT INTO csvtbl(ID,name,city) VALUES('".$col1."','".$col2."','".$col3."')";
$s     = mysql_query($query, $connect );
 }
    fclose($handle);
}

echo "File data successfully imported to database!!";
mysql_close($connect);
?>
```

Comment: Did you try with PHP? Can you add the code you have so far that imports all the columns to your question?

Comment: @don'tpanic plz check the code

Comment: I don't see any way this code could insert fifteen columns. Your insert statement only inserts three columns. Which columns are you wanting to insert?